# Finding elements matching a set of tag names using lxml

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

How do I use lxml to find elements matching a set of tag names?

Let's say I want to find all `a` and `c` elements in the following XML tree:

```
<foo>
    <a/>
    <b/>
    <c/>
</foo>
```

How would I do that? I would like to do something similar to `foo.findall('./(a|b)')` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in the right track using union operator, but the correct syntax should be as follow :

```
foo.xpath('*[self::a|self::b]')
```

or simply :

```
foo.xpath('a|c')
```

Notice how `xpath()` is preferred over `findall()` because the former provides full support for XPath 1.0 while the latter only supports a limited subset of XPath 1.0 expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex with `xpath()`. See [Regular expressions in XPath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#regular-expressions-in-xpath)

```
html = '''<foo>
    <a/>
    <b/>
    <c/>
</foo>'''

import lxml.html

data = lxml.html.fromstring(html)

result = data.xpath('./*[re:match(local-name(), "a|b")]', namespaces={'re': "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"})

print(result)
#print(list(x.tag for x in result))
```